# Find prob. that only select red balls from $n$ (red+blue) balls

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

There are 4 blue balls and 6 red balls(total 10 balls). $X$ is a random variable of the number of selected balls(without replacement), in which
$$P(X=1)=0.1$$
$$P(X=2)=0.5$$
$$P(X=3)=0.2$$
$$P(X=4)=0.1$$
$$P(X=10)=0.1$$

Then, what is probability of only selecting red balls?

This is what I have tried:

The (conditional) probability that all $r$ of the balls are selected from the red is just: ${6\choose r}\big/{10\choose r}$, for $0\leq r\leq 6$ , and $0$ elsewhere.

That is, let $N_R$ be the number of red balls selected, and $N_r$ the total number of balls selected, then:
$$\mathsf P(N_r=N_R\mid N_r=r) = \frac{6!/(6-r)!}{10!/(10-r)!} \mathbf 1_{r\in\{1\ldots 6\}}$$

As the number of balls selected is a **random variable** with the specified distribution, then the probability that all balls selected are red is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(N_R=N_r) & =\frac{1}{10}\frac{6!\,(10-1)!}{(6-1)!\,10!}+\frac 5{10}\frac{6!\,(10-2)!}{(6-2)!\,10!}+\frac{1}{5}\frac{6!\,(10-3)!}{(6-3)!\,10!}+...
\\[1ex] & 
\end{align}$$

Comment: "event that randomly select balls"??? What kind of event is that??? And how could the probability of selecting more than $10$ balls (out of $10$ balls) be larger than $0$???

Comment: I'm pretty sure you posted this question recently. It still needs some improvement. Also, again what did you try? You need to provide your thoughts and work.

Comment: @barakmanos The person means $R$ instead of $X$, so the number of balls you draw is random. And the $>10$ complaint, I said that last time too.

Comment: It's not possible to draw more than 10 balls, so it **must** be the case that $P(X > 10) =0$.

Comment: Also, you need to specify whether we draw with or without replacement.

Comment: The last line, $P(X>10)=0.1$, makes no sense. If there are $10$ balls, then the probability of drawing more than $10$ balls should be $0$.

Comment: Thank all. I updated question and my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A = \{\text{Choose only red}\}.$ Let $X$ be the number of balls drawn, and let $R$ be the number of red balls drawn. Then
\begin{align*}
P(A) &=\sum_{k = 0}^{6} P(R  = k|X = k)P(X = k)\tag 1\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{6} \frac{\binom{6}{k}}{\binom{10}{k}}p_k\\
&=\frac{\binom{6}{1}}{\binom{10}{1}}(.1)+\frac{\binom{6}{2}}{\binom{10}{2}}(.5)+\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}(.2)+\frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}(.1)+\frac{\binom{6}{5}}{\binom{10}{5}}(0)+\frac{\binom{6}{6}}{\binom{10}{6}}(0)\tag2\\
&= \frac{187}{700},
\end{align*}
where in $(1)$ it has to be the case that the number the random number you draw has to equal the number of red balls you draw; in $(2)$, $p_5 = p_6 = 0$ since according to the distribution of $X$, you cannot draw 5 or 6 times.

So, our answers agree, *almost*. If you complete your calculation (since you didn't post it), our answers should agree.

Comment: Thank for your ans. How about expected value if I trail 100 times. It will be $\frac{187}{700}\times 100$

Comment: @user2938494 Yes, if you treat each trial as an indicator with $p = 187/700$ of success, then the expectation of 100 trials is $\frac{187}{700}\times 100$. So, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is $6$ red balls, if $10$ balls are selected, probability of selecting only red balls is $0$ and we only have to consider selecting $1,2,3,4$ balls.

Let $R$ be number of red balls selected.
$$\begin{align}P(R=i|X=i)&=\frac{_6P_i}{_{10}P_i}\\
P(R=X)&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^4P(X=i)\cdot P(R=i|X=i)\\
&=0.1\cdot \frac 6{10}+0.5\cdot \frac {6\cdot5}{10\cdot9}+0.2\cdot \frac {6\cdot5\cdot4}{10\cdot9\cdot8}+0.1\cdot \frac {6\cdot5\cdot4\cdot3}{10\cdot9\cdot8\cdot7}\\
&=\frac{187}{700}\end{align}$$