# How can I compute the number of selected green ball from a given selection prob.

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have $2$ red balls in box 1 and $4$ green balls in box 2 as figure. The prob. selection the red balls (R) in box 1 is
$$P(R=1)=0.1$$
$$P(R=2)=0.9$$

[image]

And prob. selection the green balls (G) in box 2 is
$$P(G=1)=0.1$$
$$P(G=2)=0.5$$
$$P(G=3)=0.2$$
$$P(G=4)=0.2$$

The prob. select box 1 is $P(box1)=0.1$ and prob. select 2 boxes is $P(box1,box2)=0.9$. The selection of balls in each box is independent (Means selection red balls does not depend on selction of green box)

Randomly draw ball without replacement,

1. How many green balls are selected (only green balls) in 100 trails.
2. How many red balls are selected (only red balls) in 100 trails.
3. How many red and green balls are selected (include both red and green balls) in 100 trails.

Thanks in advance

This is my solution.

Due to selection balls in two boxes are independent, then prob. of sum of two random variable is

$P(Ball=2)=P(R=1)\times P(G=1)=0.01$ 
...
In mathematic, it can be represented as convlution operation

$P(Ball)=P(R)*P(G)$

Then I have the prob. selection of balls is
$$P(Balls=2)=0.01, P(Balls=3)=0.14, P(Balls=4)=0.47, P(Balls=5)=0.2, P(Balls=6)=0.18 $$

Based on the ans in [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1611774/find-prob-that-only-select-red-balls-from-n-redblue-balls) 
Let $A = \{\text{Choose only green}\}.$ Let $X$ be the number of balls drawn, and let $R$ be the number of green balls drawn. Then
\begin{align*}
P(A) &=\sum_{k = 0}^{4} P(R  = k|X = k)P(X = k)\tag 1\\
&=\sum_{k = 0}^{4} \frac{\binom{4}{k}}{\binom{6}{k}}p_k\\
&=\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}(.01)+\frac{\binom{6}{3}}{\binom{10}{3}}(.14)+\frac{\binom{6}{4}}{\binom{10}{4}}(.47)\tag2\\
&= 0.0967,
\end{align*}

In 100 trails, the selected green balls is $n_G=100 \times 0.0967 \times P(box1,box2)=6.44$

Is it correct? I am confusing about $p_k$, which one I will used (orginal $P(G)$ or $P(Balls)$

Comment: Not sure I follow.  Is it that the number of selected balls is uncertain? That is, when I choose from Box $1$, say, I might choose one red ball (probability $.1$) or I might choose two red balls (probability $.9$)?  If so then on a given trial I expect to draw $.1^*1+.9^*2=1.9$ red balls so in $100$ I expect to draw $190$ red ones, and so on.

Comment: And you need to multiply with 0.1 because selection of box 1 is 0.1 then you only has 19 red ones

Comment: But the red ones also come from second way, select both box 1 and box 2. Hence, we need to compute red ones in that way

Comment: I don't understand.  It looks like you always choose from box $1$, no?  It's only box $2$ that is uncertain.  But, honestly, the whole thing is unclear.  Can you write out the rules clearly and plainly?

Comment: Yes, the rule is that I will random chose box 1 or both box1 and box2. If box 1 is chosen, I will draw red ball in $P(R)$ distribution. If both box 1 and box 2 are chosen, then randomly select balls (red and green) by its distribution. Then compute the number of each balls after 100 trails. Is it clear?

Comment: Ok, but in that case my $190$ is correct.  The green balls need a multiplier.

Comment: Could you check my solution of green balls?

Comment: I don't understand your calculation at all.  Green Balls:  If I select from box $2$ (which I expect to do $90$ times) I expect to draw $$.1^*1+.5^*2+.2^*3+.2^*4=2.5$$

So, in totality, I expect to get $90^*2.5=225$ green balls.

Comment: You are right for 190 red balls. I think. Sorry I miscalculation about $1.9 \times 100$...

Comment: And for green balls, Because each box has own selection prob. THen I rebuild the selection of balls by compution the P(Balls). Then $p_k$ uses as $P(Balls)$.

Comment: What you write is seriously unclear.  If $A$ is the event "Choose only Green" then $P(A)=0$ because the event is impossible.  I don't understand the meaning of the combinations you take.  If all you want is the expectation, then it is unnecessary to map out all the probabilities explicitly.  Expectation is linear so you can just sort it out for a single trial and then multiply.  Of course, if you need variance and such then you have to work harder.